# append dictionaries to an array using forloop(each) in jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, for-loop

I have json data like below which i am getting from server

```
result =     [
      {"transactions": 7, "products__name": "mark"}, 
      {"transactions": 12, "products__name": "vicky"}, 
      {"transactions": 30, "products__name": "daniel"},   
      {"transactions": 6, "products__name": "hurray "}]
```

Now i want to add extra items and change key names in the dictionaries in the above json response and i want the result in the below format

```
 result =    [
        { label: "mark",  data: 7, color: "#4572A7"},
        { label: "vicky",  data: 12, color: "#4572A7"},
        { label: "daniel",  data: 30, color: "#4572A7"},
        { label: "hurray",  data: 6, color: "#4572A7"},
    ];
```

I want to do the above logic with `jquery` and done the following

```
      var array = [];
      var dictionary = {};
      $.each(result, function(key,val){
              dictionary['label'] = val.products__name;
              dictionary['data'] = val.revenue;
              dictionary['color'] = '#4572A7';
              console.log(dictionary);
            array.push(dictionary)
          });
         console.log(array);
});
```

So from the above jquery looping code, i can able to loop through the json array and can create a dictionary with different labels and items, but when  i pushed it in to the `new array`, only the starting dictionary is being repeatedly inserting in to the array like the same record is displaying 4 times in the array

So whats wrong in my code, can anyone please let me know what need to be done in order to push different dic items to new array  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [$.map()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/)

```
var colors = [' #bee485', '#f67d79', '#fdd35b', '#a8eaf7'];
var dictionary = $.map(result, function (rec, idx) {
    return {
        label: rec.products__name,
        data: rec.transactions,
        color: colors[idx % colors.length]
    }
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/t27Zt/)

Comment: how to append this dictionaries created in to a list ?, actually i want to create a list of dictionaries in the format i have mentioned in my question

Comment: k may be my terms are different, anyway i want the result in this format result =    [
        { label: "mark",  data: 7, color: "#4572A7"},
        { label: "vicky",  data: 12, color: "#4572A7"},
        { label: "daniel",  data: 30, color: "#4572A7"},
        { label: "hurray",  data: 6, color: "#4572A7"},
    ];

Comment: great and thanks, also can we do it in the way like if index = 0,  color= something, actually i want  to use this data to display a pie char using flot library, so want to add different colors to different items right ? so i am sure i will get only five items, so if index = 0 color should be #bee485, for index 1 item color should be #f67d79, 2 = #fdd35b, 3=#a8eaf7 ?